# mysql GROUP BY clause validation

Tags: mysql, sql, validation, error-handling, warnings

Suppose I have a table with the following content:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    1 |
|  4 |    1 |
|  5 |    2 |
|  6 |    2 |
|  7 |    2 |
|  8 |    2 |
+----+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now I run erroneous SQL query with `group by` clause and without any aggregation on `id` column and get wrong results:

```
mysql> select id, val from test group by val;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  5 |    2 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Can mysql client or probably some other tool validate this query and issue error or warning on using `group by` without aggregation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

> To disable the MySQL GROUP BY extension, enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`
>   SQL mode.

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

See [the documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).  Also, [this section on server modules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) may help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SQL Mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is set to *disable*. And that is the reason why your query did run without throwing any exceptions. If you don't want that behavior enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode,

- [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

**Setting the SQL Mode**

- You can set the default SQL mode by starting `mysqld` with the *--sql-mode="modes"* option, or by using *sql-mode="modes"* in `my.cnf` (Unix operating systems) or `my.ini` (Windows). modes is a list of different modes separated by comma (“,”) characters.
- You can change the SQL mode *at runtime* by using a `SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='modes'` statement to set the sql_mode system value. ex: 
  `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`